# Error import matplotlib.pyplot as plt in RStudio Server PRO / package R reticulate

Tags: python, r, rstudio, matplotlib, red-hat

Actualmente nos encontramos con el siguiente error al ejecutar el comando import matplotlib.pyplot as plt con el paquete R reticulate en RStudio Server PRO:

[image: Error]

Hemos observado que si lo ejecutamos en el exterior con un motor R 3.6 funciona:

[image: funciona]

Aunque aparece este error, tenemos las bibliotecas de cairo instaladas en Redhat:

[image: library]

RStudio version:
1.2.5033-1 Professional (Orange Blossom)
Redhat version:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)

¿Alguien se ha enfrentado a este problema con el paquete R reticulate y py matplotlib?

¿Por qué reproduzco este error?

Saludos